# method 'Container' is not defined in 'MyApp' ? In Flutter

Tags: flutter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvwcO.png

U can have this image to review Error in my Code.

Comment: Please post the code from your your question as text instead of an image.  This will allow others to copy it and answer your question a lot easier.

Comment: Error has gone now Thank you Mr.jon

Answer (score 0):

It was easy after roaming here and there on Google and all, finally i deleted my old flutter Software Development Kit Folder and replaced with new one. And that's it DONE.Now it's solved.